# mdtool, build android apk on mac

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk, mdtool

I have a Xamarin project  am looking to build a Android apk using mdtool, and the command line.
Here is the setup :

I have a mac mini - Xamarin Studio installed on it, I have the solution which build no problem.
Now from the command line this is what I an trying to do

```sh
#REM Traverse to the folder which holds the .sln file
cd One/Xamarin/Android/OneAndroid 

#REM start the build using mdtool
'/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool' -v build OneAndroid.sln
```

The above completes the build for me , however I do not get an apk file.
Could someone share with me which option needs to be added onto mdtool to generate an apk file?

Thanks
Rajesh

I understand I maybe missing some parameters for mdtool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use XBuild to compile the APK, for example:

```
xbuild MyXamarinAndroidApplication.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:SignAndroidPackage
```

This will compile the project in release mode and generate a signed and unsigned APK. If you just want an unsigned APK:

```
xbuild MyXamarinAndroidApplication.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:PackageForAndroid
```

It's worth noting that you have to specify a `.csproj`, not a `.sln`. If you give it a solution file, you'll get an error complaining that it can't find the "SignAndroidPackage" target.

Comment: Hello Tom where can I install xbuild from? It is not part of Xamarin do I get from Mono?

Comment: It's a part of Mono, which is installed by Xamarin. On my Mac, it can be found at `/usr/bin/xbuild`. Not to sure where it is on Windows - but on Windows you can use MSBuild.

Comment: Thank you for this .. I am going to try and this now.

Comment: Hello Tom,  I receive the following error : In short it cannot find CompileAndroidProject (/t:CompileAndroidProject) - if I remove the project does build "/Users/admin/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d0a702727a6205ae/NESTouch/Xamarin/Android/NESTouchAndroid/NESTouchAndroid.sln" (CompileAndroidPackage target(s)):
[15:58:42][Step 3/3]  Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
[15:58:42][Step 3/3]   Building solution configuration

Comment: "Debug|Any CPU".
[15:58:42][Step 3/3] /Users/admin/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d0a702727a6205ae/NESTouch/Xamarin/Android/NESTouchAndroid/NESTouchAndroid.sln: error : Target named 'CompileAndroidPackage' not found in the project.
[15:58:42][Step 3/3] Done building project "/Users/admin/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d0a702727a6205ae/NESTouch/Xamarin/Android/NESTouchAndroid/NESTouchAndroid.sln".--

Comment: FAILED
[15:58:42][Step 3/3] 
[15:58:42][Step 3/3] Build FAILED.
[15:58:42][Step 3/3] Errors:
[15:58:42][Step 3/3] 
[15:58:42][Step 3/3] /Users/admin/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d0a702727a6205ae/NESTouch/Xamarin/Android/NESTouchAndroid/NESTouchAndroid.sln (CompileAndroidPackage) ->
[15:58:42][Step 3/3] 
[15:58:42][Step 3/3]  /Users/admin/Downloads/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d0a702727a6205ae/NESTouch/Xamarin/Android/NESTouchAndroid/NESTouchAndroid.sln: error : Target named 'CompileAndroidPackage' not found in the project
[15:58:42][Step 3/3]   0 Warning(s)
[15:58:42][Step 3/3]   1 Error(s)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If you just want to create an unsigned APK, then you need to use `xbuild MyXamarinAndroidApplication.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:PackageForAndroid`. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hello Tom, nope the build fails - it comes back with Target named 'PackageForAndroid' not found in the project. It does build through Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Hmm, what version of Xamarin.Android do you have installed? I have the latest version (4.10.1) and it works. Alternately, you could use the `/t:SignAndroidPackage` target. That will generate an unzigned APK and a signed APK.

Comment: @TomOpgenorth can you use .sln or any other variation to create the apk using Xbuild because I have a solution that has many projects linked together and it doesn't work for the .sln because of the reasons you stated, but also for the csproj because I need to use more than one .csproj and they are in separate folders giving me the error Assemblies not found.  Or could you do multiple csproj's at once?

Comment: @GuinnessIsLife I believe now that you should be able to use the solution file: `msbuild myproject.sln`. However that will not install or sign the APK for you.

Comment: @TomOpgenorth and can you use xbuild when you are using a mac?

Comment: Because I am using Bamboo to create an IPA file and a APK file, the IPA file works but when I try to do this: `/p:Configuration=Release CustomerApp.sln` it doesn't work and I don't know why it gives the error `PCL Reference Assemblies not installed` this should not happen as it builds fine in xamarin and the IPA file had no problems creating the IPA file when using mdtool, any idea's what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: Even if I do it in the terminal xbuild /p:Confiuration=Release Customer.sln I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Check out the build process documentation from Xamarin: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/build_process/offline.pdf

Comment: Hello Jon, I have had a quick read and cannot find any reference to mdtool.

Comment: How about trying out Xbuild then? http://lipsky.me/blog/2014/1/29/r1x6nswctliiwqngg0zu63u2713cnp